# How to count how many times same key in foreach exists php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, foreach, count

I am trying to count how many times one string is in array and if its only once i want to echo this string.
This is my code :

```
<?php

global $wpdb;

$results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT id FROM wp_frm_items WHERE user_id=%d ORDER BY created_at DESC", 97));
$i = 0;

if ($results) {
    foreach($results as $row) {
        $policy_id = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_frm_item_metas WHERE field_id=%d AND item_id=%s", 203, $row->id));

        $array = array($policy_id[0]->meta_value);

        foreach ($array as $key) {
            if (array_count_values($array) == 1) {
                echo $key;
            } else {
                echo 'aaa';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to do this ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Stanislav, made an edit. Let me know if this worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

Would this help you?

```
<?php

$details = [
    0 => ["id"=>"1", "name"=>"Mike",    "num"=>"9876543210"],
    1 => ["id"=>"2", "name"=>"Carissa", "num"=>"08548596258"],
    2 => ["id"=>"1", "name"=>"Mathew",  "num"=>"784581254"],
];

function unique_multidim_array($array, $key) {
    $temp_array = [];
    $i = 0;
    $key_array = [];

    foreach($array as $val) {
        if (!in_array($val[$key], $key_array)) {
            $key_array[$i] = $val[$key];
            $temp_array[$i] = $val;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    return $temp_array;
}

$details = unique_multidim_array($details,'id'); // check on 'id' and remove duplicates

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($details);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

**The above example will output:**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "Mike"
    ["num"]=>
    string(10) "9876543210"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "Carissa"
    ["num"]=>
    string(11) "08548596258"
  }
}
```

Now you can use a foreach on this array. It skipped the duplicates.

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: One second, ill make a change.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change

```
if (array_count_values($array) == 1){
    echo $key;
}
```

to

```
if (array_count_values($array)[$key] === 1) {
    echo $key;
}
```

[array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-count-values.php) return an associative array so if you want the number of occurences of $word you need array_count_values($array)[$word].
Also I wouldn't name the value of my array "$key" in a foreach, it can be quite confusing.